# Debugging Silverlight project with Visual Studio loads file not local webserver?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I've got a Silverlight project in VS 2010 that when I go to debug, my browser is spawned, but the file:// location is attempted, rather than loading the http://localhost location.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks.

**-- Update --**

The specific error is  as follows:

> The provided URI scheme 'file' is
>   invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter
>   name: via

The error makes sense, but the reason why it's trying to load up file: rather than spawn the local server is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to have a web project to host the silverlight app. 
Second, edit your web application properties (select the project then press ALT + Enter) and add a reference to your silverlight application in the "Silverlight" tab. Now whenever you build your applications, a copy of the silverlight app will be copied to the web application.

After that, create a test page with some HTML and add an object tag with the url to the silverlight xap file.

Also, make sure your web application is set as the default startup application.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the reply.  I have all of this done already, with the reference to my Silverlight project from the web project.  Path in web is set to ClientBin, and Configuration Specific Folders = No.

Comment: @elhaix - What about making sure that the web site is the default startup project? You can check by right clicking the project and picking "Set as StartUp Project".

Comment: Thanks Matt.  For some reason, at some point, I must have changed it to the Silverlight project being the startup project, rather than the web one.  Thanks.